# Best practice to position html element using css

Tags: html, css

I am not much sound with CSS, but working with it.

I generally user `style` element with inline or css method to position element.

I dont know whether this is correct quesion or not but `relative` or `absolute` which method is good to position element?

I use `style="position:relative; left:100px; top:30px"` something like this.

is it correct way to position so that it can appear exactly same in all browsers and mobile devices also?

I appreciate if someone can give his experience and guidence which may help lot more beginners!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolute positioning is independent of its parent.

When a parent has a relative position, the child with absolute positioning is placed relative to their parent.

**For example,**

For absolute positioning,

```
<div><div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;">Abc</div></div>
```

The above will make the div go **independently** on top without any effect on parent.

For relative position,

```
<div style="position:relative;"><div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;">Abc</div></div>
```

The above will make the absolutely positioned elements be relative and **dependent** on their parent.

Comment: +1, but I feel it needs to stress that **absolute positioning is dependent on the *nearest ancestor* that has positioning, not necessarily the immediate parent.** I found that concept took me a while to get my head around when I was learning it.

Comment: Thx for upvote. I agree, but the nearest ancestor would be the immediate parent where the absolutely positioned div would be nested. If not, I would be greatful if you can elaborate your views further. - @Dre

Comment: To clarify: in your example, yes, the immediate parent is the closest ancestor with positioning, in which case it would be the reference point for the absolutely positioned div. I was pointing out that this isn't *always* the case: in your first example the immediate parent doesn't have positioning, so doesn't affect the child. However, in a real world scenario there might be another element higher up the DOM that *does* have positioning, which would affect the child. See [this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FekWt/)
I only point this out because of how many times this has tripped me up!

Comment: Exactly, as you are using specificity of `#example_2 .parent`. But lets read the first line of the OP where he says that __`I am not much sound with CSS`__. so its good information for him, provided he gets sound enough with the basics first. Thx for taking out time to provide with further info - @Dre

Comment: @Nathan_Lee I agree, getting the basics is important, without getting bogged down too much in the details. However, in my opinion understanding how the positioning system with regards to ancestors is pretty crucial. Well done to both of us!

Comment: Yes. Agreed +1 - @Dre

Comment: @NathanLee: thanks aton. This clears my doubt! thanks to-Dre too for your interest and clarification!

Answer (score 4):

Use this website, this is how I practiced CSS

http://learnlayout.com/

Comment: +1 For having some good examples on that link

Comment: no problem :) yes, it is a very simple and handy website for understanding the basics of css layouts

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla's [MDN states:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> **relative** Lay out all elements as though the element were not
>   positioned, and then adjust the element's position, without changing
>   layout (and thus leaving a gap for the element where it would have
>   been had it not been positioned). The effect of position:relative on
>   table-*-group, table-row, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption
>   elements is undefined.

Which basically means each element is a block, which comes after the one before it, and takes up screen space- the subsequent element will take up the next available space following it.

> **absolute**
>   Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a
>   specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor or to
>   the containing block. Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins,
>   they do not collapse with any other margins.

Which means the element will appear at a specified place (relative to it's parent, or the nearest parent with a position property) regardless of other content.

In terms of **best practice** - there is none, it is dependant on the effect you wish to achieve, in which case the best practice is to use the position property designed for that purpose.

In terms of **mobile devices** you may want to look at **[responsive web design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)**, a framework like **[Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)** will not only take care of this for you, but also provides a very accessible and quick means to start building out your site(s).

Answer (score 0):

If you're not familiar with CSS, I highly recommend you to use a CSS framework like [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) (or another grid system, like [960 grid](http://960.gs/), if you don't want all the Bootstrap styles).

Because making your design responsive from scratch is a headache and you will loose lots of time to make it works.

Comment: But if you follow that path, how will you *learn?*

Comment: I'm agree but when you're newbie in CSS, position and responsiveness is too advanced. There are lots of other things to learn and understand before build a responsive layout from scratch. Using a framework permits to have good results before be able to make it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The `absolute` positioning is best if you need something the be placed at an *exact* coordinate. The `relative` positioning will take where the element already is, and add the coordinates to it. So for example if I have a `<p>` element inside of a `<div>` and I want to indent it, I would use `relative` with, say, `left:15;`. As for appearing the same in all browsers; this is nigh impossible. There will always be that one browser that doesn't conform. But `absolute` and `relative` will both generally work.

Answer (score 0):

first thing I would suggest is to avoid inline CSS for performance and maintenance issues; hover I would undertake a CSS online course such as:

- http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web
- http://learnlayout.com/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/css (one of the best resources on the web)